# MVC 4 - sorting with LINQ doesn't work with Ajax.BeginForm and my For loop

Tags: list, asp.net-mvc-4, sorting, lambda

I writing some code with C# and MVC and I have button for sorting a list of data by asc and desc. The logic works in my controller, I am able to call the method that sorts the list and in the breakpoint I can see that it has been sorted.

But it's weird because when I loop through my list in the partial view it never works. I use a breakpoint in my view to make sure it's the same order of items which it is. But it's like the new values don't render to the screen.

**TeamManagement.cshtml**

```
@model Website.Models.modelTeamSelect

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Football App";
}
@section featured {

}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_PartialTeams",
    new
    {
        model = this.Model
    },
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        UpdateTargetId = "divCreatedTeams",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
    }))
{

    <div id="divTeams" style="float: left; padding: 10px;">
        <h3>Create a new team:</h3>

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.team.TeamName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.team.TeamName)
        <input type="submit" value="Add Team" name="btnSubmit" />

    </div>

    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Partials/_PartialTeams.cshtml");
}
```

**_PartialTeams.cshtml**

```
@model Website.Models.modelTeamSelect
 <div id="divCreatedTeams" style="float: left; padding: 10px;">
<h3>Your created teams:</h3>
<input type="submit" value="Asc" name="btnSubmit" />
<input type="submit" value="Desc" name="btnSubmit" />
<br />
@if (Model.teams.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.teams.Count; i++)
    {
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.teams[i].TeamName)
    <input type="button" value="Update team name" name="btnSubmit"/>
    <input type="button" value="Remove team" name="btnSubmit"/>
    <br />
    }
}
</div>
```

**Sorting logic in my controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public PartialViewResult _PartialTeams(string BtnSubmit, modelTeamSelect modelTeamSelect)
        {
            switch (BtnSubmit)
            {
                case "Add Team":
                    modelTeamSelect.teams.Add(modelTeamSelect.team);
                    break;
                case "Asc":
                    FootballRepository = new Repository.FootballRepository();
                    modelTeamSelect.teams = FootballRepository.Sort(modelTeamSelect, BtnSubmit);
                    break;
                case "Desc":
                    FootballRepository = new Repository.FootballRepository();
                    modelTeamSelect.teams = FootballRepository.Sort(modelTeamSelect, BtnSubmit);
                    break;
            }
            return PartialView("~/Views/Partials/_PartialTeams.cshtml", modelTeamSelect);
        }

public List<Models.modelTeam> Sort(Models.modelTeamSelect modelTeamSelect, string sort)
        {
            switch (sort)
            {
                case "Asc":
                    modelTeamSelect.teams = modelTeamSelect.teams.OrderBy(t => t.TeamName).ToList();
                    break;
                case "Desc":
                    modelTeamSelect.teams = modelTeamSelect.teams.OrderByDescending(t => t.TeamName).ToList();
                    break;
            }
            return modelTeamSelect.teams;
        }
```

**My main model with team collection**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Website.Models
{
    public class modelTeamSelect
    {
        public modelTeamSelect()
        {
            teams = new List<modelTeam>();
            team = new modelTeam();
        }

        public List<modelTeam> teams { get; set; }
        public modelTeam team { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My method Sort does it's job but in the view it never displays correctly. e.g. always wrong order.

Anyone have any ideas because I am stuck.

**Screenshots**

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the screenshots I click sort by Asc and you can see it says Newcastle as the first item in the list. But when the page renders it will say West Ham first even though it is iterating using the for loop.

Comment: It seems that you have Sort methods in multiple locations.  One in your controller and another in FootballRepository.  Is this the case?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to know what type modelTeamSelect.teams actually is.  Is it a List<SelectListItem> ?

Comment: @AaronPalmer FootballRepository is a class where the sorting happens but I plan to refactor that later. I'll admit it's slightly over engineered but the problem is in the view. I'll attach a screenshot and the model class.

Comment: Anybody, I am baffled why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the Html helpers are preferring to use  the `ModelState` values over the actual model values.

So even you have sorted in place your `modelTeamSelect.teams` in your action in the view  `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.teams[i].TeamName)` call will use the original (before sorting) values form the `ModelState`.

The solution: if you are updating your action parameters in-place then just clear the `ModelState` before returning the View/PartialView:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult _PartialTeams(string BtnSubmit, 
    modelTeamSelect modelTeamSelect)
{
    // ... Do the sorting, etc.

    ModelState.Clear();
    return PartialView("~/Views/Partials/_PartialTeams.cshtml", modelTeamSelect);
}
```

You can read more about why the helpers are working like this in this article: [ASP.NET MVC Postbacks and HtmlHelper Controls ignoring Model Changes](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Apr/20/ASPNET-MVC-Postbacks-and-HtmlHelper-Controls-ignoring-Model-Changes)

Comment: thanks for this I'll check it out and let you know how it goes!

Comment: @nemsev Thank you! I knew I was missing something and I was. I added ModelState.Clear() and it worked.

Comment: Clearing ModelState removes all the validation errors, warnings. This is not ideal.